# Creating MemberAcces with ExpressionTree to a complex type

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression, expression-trees

I'd like to dynamically create a MemberAcess Expression to a deeper level then 1 (recursively):

```
public class Job
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Salary { get; set; }
}
public class Employee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Job Job { get; set; }
}
```

And I want to dynamically create a list of MemberAccesExpressions for each property in Employee and each property in Employee's complex members, the outcome should be something like this:

```
MemberAccesExpression[] {
    { e => e.Name },
    { e => e.Job.Name },
    { e => e.Job.Name }
}
```

This is a pseudo code of what I got:

```
List list = new List();
public Expression<Func<TModel, dynamic>> CreateME<TModel>(TModel model)
{
        var type = typeof (TModel);
        var properties = type.GetProperties();
        foreach (var prop in properties)
        {
            // I want to ignore collections
            if (typeof(ICollection).IsAssignableFrom(prop.PropertyType)) continue;

            // Recall for complex property
            if (prop.PropertyType.Namespace != "System")
            {
                // CreateME(model, ) // THIS IS WHEN I DON'T KNOW WHAT TO DO
                continue;
            }

            var param = Expression.Parameter(type, "x");
            var memberAccess = Expression.PropertyOrField(param, prop.Name);
            list.Add(Expression.Lambda<Func<TModel, dynamic>>(memberAccess, param));
        }
}
```

How do I make this a recursive method?
I thought of adding an optional parameter named 
    (TModel model, Expression> baseMemberAccess = null)
and somehow concat the member expression to baseMemberAccess if it's not null.

P.S.
is there's a better way to determine if a Type is not atomic type then this
    (prop.PropertyType.Namespace != "System")
? (not int,float,string,etc...)

Appreciate any help,
Adam

**An edit for trying to lay it more simply:**

If I want to create an expression tree of a member access to Employee.Name this is what I do:

```
        var param = Expression.Parameter(type, "x");
        var memberAccess = Expression.PropertyOrField(param, memberName);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<TModel, TMember>>(memberAccess, param);
```

What is the equivalent to this for a member access to Employee.Job.Salary ?

Comment: I sense an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/168269). What problem do you want to solve with your code?

Comment: I don't think it's not clear, but I edited the question and added my exact problem at the end,,

Comment: He's asking what is the bigger problem your trying to solve? Why are you trying to collect all the member expressions of an object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public IEnumerable<Expression<Func<TModel, dynamic>>> CreateME<TModel>()
    {
        var stack = new Stack<StackItem>();
        var type = typeof(TModel);
        var parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(type, "x");
        stack.Push(new StackItem(typeof(TModel), parameterExpression));

        while (stack.Count > 0)
        {
            var currentItem = stack.Pop();
            var properties = currentItem.PropertyType.GetProperties();
            foreach (var property in properties)
            {
                if (IsComplexProperty(property))
                    stack.Push(new StackItem(property.PropertyType, Expression.PropertyOrField(currentItem.AccessChainExpression, property.Name)));
                else
                {
                    yield return GetSimplePropertyExpression<TModel>(parameterExpression, currentItem.AccessChainExpression, property.Name);
                }
            }
        }


    }

    private static Expression<Func<TModel, dynamic>> GetSimplePropertyExpression<TModel>(ParameterExpression lhs, Expression accessChain, string propertyName)
    {
        var memberAccess = Expression.Convert(Expression.PropertyOrField(accessChain, propertyName), typeof(object));
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<TModel, dynamic>>(memberAccess, lhs);
    }

    private static bool IsComplexProperty(PropertyInfo p)
    {
        return !typeof (ICollection).IsAssignableFrom(p.PropertyType) && p.PropertyType.Namespace != "System";
    }


    class StackItem
    {
        public StackItem(Type propertyType, Expression accessChainExpression)
        {
            PropertyType = propertyType;
            AccessChainExpression = accessChainExpression;
        }

        public Type PropertyType { get; private set; }
        public Expression AccessChainExpression { get; private set; }
    }
```

Im sure it can be improved, but this should work.

Comment: I'm afraid this neither doesn't work or I have no idea how to use it. At this line - Expression.Convert(Expression.PropertyOrField(accessChain, propertyName), typeof(object)); I get this exception - "'memberName' is not a member of type 'System.Func`2[TModel,System.Object]'"

Comment: I've only tested it for the example objects, can you post the actual class definition you are using for TModel.

Comment: Does your actual TModel contain properties that are Func's?